# Can I send a "click" to an href in asp code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, .net

There is a complex function written in jquery that runs if the href below is clicked by the user.  Is there any way I can simulate this click in the code behind of the asp form?  In other words, I need to "click" the href called "shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_link" from my code behind to prepopulate this input.  Can anyone assist?

```
<div class="no"><label class="label-1" for="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_not_acceptable">Not Acceptable</label></div>
<a href="#" class="toggle" runat="server" id="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_link"></a>
<div class="yes"><label class="label-2" for="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_acceptable">Acceptable</label></div>
<label class="universal-label"></label>

<input type="radio" id="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_not_acceptable" name="shipping-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered" value="Not Acceptable" runat="server">
<input type="radio" id="shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_acceptable" name="shipping-question-ID-product-received-as-ordered" value="Acceptable" checked="true" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ArindamNayak had the right idea, but there may be issues with his implementation.  If you add the below script to your code-behind, you will achieve what I believe is your desired result:

```
var autoRunScript = string.Format("<script>$(function() {{ $('#{0}').click(); }} );</script>", shipping_question_ID_product_received_as_ordered_link.ClientID);
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("keyClientBlock", autoRunScript);
```

The difference here is that without wrapping your `$(link).click()` in a `ready` handler, jQuery may not process the command correctly.  Additionally, you have to be careful with the ID that you use as it could be modified to include containers.

Comment: I got "Input string was not in a correct format..."

Comment: I forgot to use double {{ }} in the string.Format for the javascript.  Sorry.

Comment: You're my hero. This worked like a charm!!!! Thank you so much, I stewed over this for hours

Answer (score 0):

You can use following.

```
 string jScript;
    jScript="<script>$('#linkid').click()</script>";
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("keyClientBlock",jScript);
```

So this will add a JS code block programatically to aspx and this JS will execute to click the a href ( having id = "linkid"